# Move local VS project GIT to Team visual studio on-line project GIT

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I have a solution in VS 2013.  I've set GIT as the source control and have a local repository.  I would also like to have one that I can commit changes to that resides at my visual studio on-line account.  Sounds fairly straight forward, but in 4 hours I've learned how to create a NEW team project, but I am unable to MOVE/COPY/PUSH or otherwise make a duplicate of the local repo to the on-line version.

If I create a new project on-line and then select it, it opens an empty solution in Visual Studio.

You would think that there are numerous people who have this same problem, yet I am unable to find anything that explains how to do this.  Yes, I am new to GIT and VS on-line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to create the project in Visual Studio on-line in order to push your code there.  Do that first.  **IT NEEDS TO HAVE THE SAME NAME**

After the project is created you will have this screen.  The important parts are in red.  Note from VS local you can open a command prompt window.  It needs to be in the same directory as the repository locally so if you do it directly be sure to change the directory to the root of your local repository.
[image]

Comment: The name is immaterial

Comment: Not true.  I named my visual studio on-line project differently and every time I tried to push I got an error in the command prompt window.  And although I don't have time to go and find the MSDN reference there was one about naming your on-line projects and that in some cases they were required to be the same name as the local version.

Comment: There is no such requirement. You need to change the origin path to the new location or add an additional one. Name can be anything that you want in all circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the VSO project has Git support. If you opted for TFVC, you must re-create it.

In Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 (not sure for previous versions), in Team Explorer, select the **Unsynched Commits** button and fill-in the **Publish to Remote Repository** with the Git repository in VSO. You can find this URL in the **Code** tab below the message «*To clone this repository in Git, use the following URL:*».